# WPF control for showing status messages

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Im building a small Poker application with WPF.
I want to integrate a control that shows what happened in the game.
In the end it should output something like this:

```
CPU 1 folded.
CPU 2 raised by 30.
CPU 3 called.
```

The messages themselves I would of course generate in my code, but I dont know which control suits my need and how I would bind it to the messages (or how I handle the messages).
Ideally it would add new messages at the bottom and could even have a scroll bar or just move the oldest messages out to the top.

Comment: Status Bar is cool but honestly just make your own control if you want full customization.

Comment: How about a toast style notification?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a new control just use the built in ListView control and bind it to an `ObservableCollection<string>` that contains all your status message.

Comment: Great thats works like a charm. To have the newest message always displayed I insert them at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use PopUp. Check component `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification` which is available via NuGet package manager